# Jest test for function containing function calls within in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test for a function which is called when the `onChange` event is fired in a dropdown containing 'currencies codes'.
I'm stuck at writing the test for it as it is calling multiple other functions within and am completely new to this framework.

How could I achieve this to test the logic here?

Here's what I've achieved so far!

```
test('should verify currency change logic', () => {
    const myComponent = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    expect(myComponent.instance().onCurrencyChange('USD').props().location.query.currency).toEqual('USD');
});
```

my function:

```
onCurrencyChange = (currencyCode) => {
    const { location: { query, pathname } } = this.props;
    this.props.setCountry(this.props.criteria.country, currencyCode).then(() =>
        this.props.actionUpdateURLQuery('URL_UPDATE_QUERY', pathname, extend(query, { currency: currencyCode })));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `expect(function()).toHaveBeenCalled()` function. But you will need to need to have the function you want to test set to a mock function using `jest.fn()`.

See here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeencalled